# VLC player too slow on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: video, vlc

I have a new laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.1 and VLC media player 3.0.4. But VLC performs worse than an old version on my over 10 years old Win XP machine. The video clips have 720x576 H264 with AAC audio. VLC always cuts off some frames at the beginning and at the end, just like the "cheap" players. I already disabled MP4 deblocking and enabled real-time mode, but no noticeable effect. I am rather new to Linux and don't know whether/where there are settings (VLC or Ubuntu) that would enhance video playback and am grateful for hints.

Comment: Hmmm. My VLC plays enormous files perfectly, so perhaps it's not the application.

Comment: While VLC is playing, run `top` to see if perhaps you are running low on CPU or RAM resources.

Comment: Top says that VLC uses 35 to 45 % CPU and 3 % memory. On 2nd place is gnome-shell with 20 % CPU and 8 % memory. The rest is in the 1 digit range. Does VLC have a buffer setting or similar that could be increased, I had such a problem once with a tv-stick.

Comment: i suggest it has something to do with hardware acceleration: whats your graphics card, check if it's hw acceleration is enabled. Can you play youtube videos at high resolution without any issues?

Comment: Now I've increased all of VLC's buffers, but no effect. I even applied all the tips to speed up Ubuntu in general (temp dir to RAM, reduce swappiness...), so that my system runs as fine as never before, but no effect on the video playback problem. The one thing that did not work was to change the video driver from xserver-xorg-video-intel to modesetting, but I doubt that this is a video driver issue. I think the underlying problem is that the players are busy with other things when they start or stop playing, so that they chew up the video. The VLC buffers seem to apply only _during_ playback.

Comment: Recently I noticed that the old VLC installation that performs well is a portable one. This confirms my opinion that the player is busy with other things, which do not occur with a portable version.

Answer (score 2):

I worked around a performance problem with MP3 playback in VLC (a lag after jumping back a few seconds) by installing MPV:

```
sudo apt install mpv
```

See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/swap-vlc-mpv-ubuntu

---

Also VLC player seems to have a better performance when not installed via the Software Center but via apt.

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

Comment: Just tried mpv and yes it's performing much better in this respect!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can share my experience with a disclaimer that I am not an expert. The opening time for VLC had gotten higher, every time I pressed (skip 5 sec) I would have had to wait for 3-4 seconds for the video to play at the required frame rate. I thought the cache and other files VLC stores were slowing it down, **so I searched for VLC files all over my Linux LXDE and deleted them all.** These included config files too. I did this because uninstalling and reinstalling VLC had no effect and I had not cleared cache, so I deleted those files (VLC config and other vlc files) and it's as good as the first time.
***Warning: Have a good look at your config and keep it simple, this method will for sure delete your configuration and you would have to redo it.***

Comment: If you don't mind losing your VLC config, you can just remove or rename directory `$HOME/.config/vlc`. That should result in clean install behavior for VLC. Note that your file manager may hide the dot-files by default so you may need to do something similar to View - Show hidden files.